# How to control null deserialization with default values and required values in Jackson with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jackson

Using Jackson 2.9.6

**I have the following data class definition:**

```
data class SomeDTO @JsonCreator internal constructor
(
    @get:JsonProperty(value = "first-property", required = true)
    @param:JsonProperty(value = "first-property", required = true)
    val firstProperty: Long?,

    @get:JsonProperty(value = "second-property")
    @param:JsonProperty(value = "second-property")
    val secondProperty: Int = 1234

    @get:JsonProperty("third-property", required = true)
    @param:JsonProperty("third-property", required = true)
    val thirdProperty: Int
)
```

**What I expect for a JSON that deserializes into SomeDTO**

1. If `firstProperty` is missing, it should throw an exception.
2. If `firstProperty` is null, it should assign null since it is nullable.
3. If `secondProperty` is missing or null it should assign the default value of `1234`
4. If `thirdProperty` is missing or null, it should throw an exception.

Basically that I can control which values can be deserialized and into what.

**What I am experiencing:**

If *not* using KotlinModule then (1), (2), and (4) work but (3) fails with:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot map `null` into type int (set DeserializationConfig.DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES to 'false' to allow)

If using KotlinModule then (2), (3), and (4) work but (1) fails.

**Main part of ObjectMapper configuration:**

```
disable(
        MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_CREATORS,
        MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_FIELDS,
        MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS,
        MapperFeature.AUTO_DETECT_IS_GETTERS
       )
disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)

registerModule(ParanamerModule())
registerModule(KotlinModule()) // Might be registered or not

disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE)
enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES)
```

I think it is easier to use the KotlinModule but I don't know how to tell it to not auto assign null values to nullable fields when the property is missing in the JSON

Comment: Have you tried `@field` in place of `@get` or `@param`?

Comment: @jaco0646 Yes I have, and didn't work. If I am not mistaken that shouldn't work anyways since I need to annotate the constructor parameters foremost

Comment: You're right. I missed the `@JsonCreator` annotation.

Comment: Try updating to version 2.9.7. There is a bug fix (#168) that may address the issue you are seeing in the Kotlin module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the Kotlin module to version 2.9.7 produces an exception when `firstProperty` is missing. I've tested it repeatedly, going back and forth between 2.9.6 and 2.9.7 with the code and configuration copied from the OP.

A bug fix in 2.9.7 matches the unexpected behavior described in the OP.

> Fixes #168 where `JsonProperty(required=true)` was being ignored and overridden by nullability check

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/168

Comment: Weird... I tried it yesterday and didn't work. I will try again then!

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
data class SomeDTO(
        @JsonProperty(value = "first-property", required = true)
        val firstProperty: Long?,

        @JsonProperty(value = "second-property")
        val secondProperty: Int = 1234,

        @JsonProperty("third-property", required = true)
        val thirdProperty: Int
)
```

A few notes:

1.
Since you are using the primary constructor for your annotated fields, in Kotlin you don't need the `@JsonCreator` annotation.

This is what the [GitHub page of the Jackson project](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations#using-constructors-or-factory-methods) says:

> By default, Jackson tries to use the "default" constructor (one that
>   takes no arguments), when creating value instances. But you can also
>   choose to use another constructor, or a static factory method to
>   create instance. To do this, you will need to use annotation
>   @JsonCreator, and possibly @JsonProperty annotations to bind names to
>   arguments

2. You dont need the separate `@get` and `@param` annotations. `@JsonProperty` alone is sufficient for your use-case.

Comment: Even though what you proposed saved me some redundant code it still didn't solve my problem while using the KotlinModule

Comment: Expectation (1) when using the KotlinModule is not throwing an exception

Comment: @IS1_SO even if the value is required, if you make it nullable that's the default value in case it is missing.. I don't think you can explicitely require it, when it is nullable.